# Pandas insert into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I've read in an excel file with 5 columns into a dataframe (using Pandas) and I'm trying to write it to an existing empty sql server table using this code

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
PRCcrsr.execute("Insert into table([Field1], [Field2], [Field3], [Field4], [Field5]) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"
                , row['dfcolumn1'],row['dfcolumn2'], row['dfcolumn3'], row['dfcolumn4'], row['dfcolumn5'])
```

I get the following error message:
TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 5 positional arguments but 7 were given

df.shape says I have 5 columns but when I print the df to the screen it includes the RowNumber.  Also one of the columns is city_state which includes a comma.  Is this the reason it thinks I'm providing 7 arguments(5 actual columns + row number + the comma issue)? Is there a way to deal with the comma and rowindex columns in the dataframe before writing in to SQL Server? If shape says 5 columns why am I getting this error?

Comment: Check `pd.to_sql`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above indicated 7 parameters were being passed to the cursor execute command and only between 2 and 5 are permissible.  I am actually passing 7 parameters (Insert into, Values, and  row[dfcolumn1, 2, 3, 4, 5  - 7 in all).  The fix was to convert the row[dfcolumn1] to a tuple using this code

```
new tuple = [tuple(r) for r in df.values.tolist()]
```

then I rewrote the for loop as follows:

```
for tuple in new_tuple: 
     PRCcrsr.execute = Insert into table([Field1], [Field2], [Field3], [Field4], [Field5]) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", tuple)
```

This delivered the fields as a tuple and inserted correctly